# Read images from two different folders and list the image directories with name in a csv file

Tags: python, image, file, image-processing

There are two image folders names: bad_pictures and good_pictures. Two folders represent two different classes. I am trying to write a python script to make a CSV/JSON file which will contain two columns, one is **CONTENT( full path of the images)**  and another one is **LABEL( bad or good)**. Like:

[image]

As far I can remember that we may get the images from a single folder with:

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
image_list = []
for filename in glob.glob('yourpath/*.jpg'): 
    im=Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(im)
```

which is far from my goal. I am hopping your help to figure our the codes to reach my goal.

Comment: Why do you need `PIL` here? You have `n = 2` labels, and all images with each label are in their own directory. As such, you just need to enumerate the files in each directory (e.g. via `pathlib`) and yield the path plus the label (which is a function of the path).

Comment: As you just want to store image path and label only then you probably don't require to read image, just try to read name of the file and directory name for these two columns

Comment: @Hetal and crcvd: thanks for your comments, Can you please share the code?

Comment: @TazimTaz Please check posted solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below to generate csv file:

```
import csv
import glob
path = "d:/so/good_pictures/*.*"
gp=glob.glob(path)
path = "d:/so/bad_pictures/*.*"
bp=glob.glob(path)
with open('test2.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["CONTENT", "LABEL"])
    for element in gp:
        writer.writerow([element, "good"])
    for element in bp:
        writer.writerow([element, "bad"])
```